# Locally free extension of locally free sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Given a coherent sheaf $F$ on a smooth variety $X$, we know that $F$ is locally free on an open subset $U$ in $X$ outside a codimension two subset. Say the rank is $k$.

Is  there a locally free sheaf $E$ of rank $k$ on $X$ together with a map $E\rightarrow F$, at least on $U$?

In other words, does the restriction $F_U$ admit a locally free extension on $X$?

Usually coherent extensions are subsheaves of $j_*F_U$, but I dont know if one can have a locally free extension of the locally free $F_U$, on $X$.

Answer (score 15):

Since you assumed that $X$ is smooth (less would be enough, but you need at least $S_2$), $G=j_*F_U$ is *reflexive*, that is $G^{\ast\ast}=G$ where $G^{*}=\mathscr Hom_X(G,\mathscr O_X)$ is the dual.

If two reflexive sheaves agree on an open set with a codimension $2$ complement, then they agree, so your question is equivalent to asking that $G$ be locally free.

If the rank of $F$ is $1$, then $G$ corresponds to a divisor and again since $X$ is smooth it is Cartier and hence $G$ is locally free.

If the rank of $F$ is at least $2$, then the locus where a reflexive sheaf is not locally free is at least $3$-codimensional (see Lemma 1.1.10 in [Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces, by Okonek, Schneider, Spindler](http://books.google.com/books?id=OG348syTqC8C&lpg=PA75&vq=1.1.10&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

So what you want can be done on curves and surfaces, but not necessarily on varieties of dimension $\geq 3$. An alternative way to get $G$ is to take the double dual of $F$, that is, $G=F^{\ast\ast}$. In other words, your question is whether that is locally free.

To complete the picture look at Example 1.1.13 in [ibid](http://books.google.com/books?id=OG348syTqC8C&lpg=PA75&vq=1.1.10&pg=PA75#v=onepage&q&f=false). That shows that reflexive sheaves of rank $\geq 2$ are not always locally free.

To summarize:

- If $k=1$ or $\dim X\leq 2$ then the sheaf you are looking for is $j_*F_U$
- Otherwise, if $j_*F_U$ is locally free you've got it, if it is not, then there is no such sheaf.